# Golang, how to use a struct to write JSON response over HTTP?

Tags: http, go

**The Goal:**

Using github.com/neelance/graphql-go starwars example, I'm trying to write a JSON response to my ReactJS client. That struct stuff is completely new for me, Golang as well btw.

**The question:**

What should `data` variable be in order to get the appropriate response to the following example GraphQL query?

```graphql
query clientQuery {
  character(id: 1000) {
    name
    appearsIn
  }
}
```

**Additional info:**

From what I've read here and there, `data` must be some kind of struct. I've got plenty of structs available in the example (see starwars.go below).

**The Code to be modified (main.go):**

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/neelance/graphql-go"
    "github.com/neelance/graphql-go/example/starwars"
    "github.com/neelance/graphql-go/relay"
)

var schema *graphql.Schema

func init() {
    schema = graphql.MustParseSchema(starwars.Schema, &starwars.Resolver{})
}

func main() {

    port := ":8080"
    log.Printf(`GraphQL server starting up on http://localhost%v`, port)

    http.Handle("/query", &relay.Handler{Schema: schema})

    http.HandleFunc("/graphql", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        // THIS IS SUPER WRONG, data should be something
        // like data := starwars.Resolver{} or so?
        data := `{"data":{"character":{"name":"Luke Skywalker","appearsIn":["NEWHOPE","EMPIRE","JEDI"]}}}`

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, nil))
}
```

**REFERENCE 1 - [starwars.go](https://github.com/neelance/graphql-go/blob/master/example/starwars/starwars.go)**

**REFERENCE 2 - [relay.go](https://github.com/neelance/graphql-go/blob/master/relay/relay.go)**

Comment: Can you come up with a short problem description and a clear question? Sending JSON via HTTP is so simple but you show so much code...

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: @Volker, what I'm trying to achieve is indeed "so simple", I just don't have the knowledge yet for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is a bit confusing. <s>You are asking about JSON, but your wanted response is not in a valid JSON format:</s> *It looks like you added unrelated GraphQL information.*

I am not sure if this is an question about GraphQL or JSON. I will try to answer it anyway.

Your example `data` looks like this, therefore I assume that is the result you want to generate:

```
data := `{"data":{"character":{"name":"Luke Skywalker","appearsIn":["NEWHOPE","EMPIRE","JEDI"]}}}`
```

A clean way to make Go generate a proper JSON is to create Structs which contain the data:

```
type Response struct {
    Data Data `json:"data"`
}

type Data struct {
    Character Character `json:"characer"`
}

type Character struct {
    Name      string   `json:"name"`
    AppearsIn []string `json:"appearsIn"`
}
```

Then you can define the data like this:

```
    data := Response{
        Data: Data{
            Character: Character{
                Name:      "Luke Skywalker",
                AppearsIn: []string{"NEWHOPE", "EMPIRE", "JEDI"},
            },
        },
    }
```

Perhaps this question isn't about JSON rather than GraphQL. In this case you need to clarify your question.

**References**

- Details about JSON tags (ie `json:".."`): https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal
- Example with Structs: https://gobyexample.com/structs

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was struggling to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler example, which would have helped me if it had been here.

```
type Password struct {
    Password string `json:"password"`
}

func keyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    response := Password{"password"}

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
}
```